# Can I create Let’s Encrypt certificate for my domain from macOS?

Tags: ssl-certificate, mac, lets-encrypt

I have a domain parking that returns a security error for HTTPS and is not possible to create a Let’s Encrypt certificate on the server, but it is possible to upload a certificate.

Would it be possible to create a Let’s Encrypt certificate from my Mac and upload it?  I have FTP access to the domain root.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to be able to server `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<TOKEN>` ([HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge)) or DNS record `_acme-challenge.example.com` with the token ([DNS-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge)).

Either way you have to do it from a server, not from a client OS; unless your MacOS is your web server or your DNS server, you can't create a Let's Encrypt certificate from it. Furthermore, Let's Encrypt certificates are only valid for three months. This means you really need an automated renewal procedure.

Comment: I can edit DNS or dd a file via FTP but if Let's Encrypt certificate  has maximum expire date of 3 mouths is not suitable for my pompous

Comment: Modern browsers won't trust certificates older than a year anyway, so if you want a long lived solution you are going to need to update regularly. LetsEncrypt use 90days to basically force you into the very good habit of automating this task